# Find which git branches have been merged to branch x, but are not yet in master?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-branch

I have a branch "UAT" which several feature branches will be merged into for testing. How can I get a list of the branches currently merged into "UAT" which are NOT yet merged to master?

So consider this UAT branch (branched off master) with 2 other branches merged into it:

UAT

- JIRA-001
- JIRA-002

So I want a command which will show that UAT currently has "JIRA-001" and "JIRA-002" merged into it.

Now if I merged JIRA-001 to master, I want that same command to show that UAT currently has only JIRA-002 merged into it.

Is this possible? I've been playing around with different combinations of `git branch --merged` based on other answers on here but it's not getting me the results I want.

**EDIT 1** - I pretty much want this `git log | grep "into UAT" | sort -u` but with an extra bit of them disappearing when they're merged into master (but can't figure that part out!).

Comment: You seem to need something like `git rev-list --right-only --format='%m %D' --simplify-by-decoration master...UAT` that produces a right-only ref-diff between two refs, master and UAT respectively. Additionally, `| awk 'FNR % 2 == 0` to get rid of the `commit ...` lines (I wish I could know whether git can do the awk job itself).

Comment: @fluffy This seems to work too, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 comm -3 <(git branch -a --merged master|sort -u) <(git branch -a --merged UAT|sort -u)
```

This should get you the branches which are merged either only in master or UAT.
You can play with comm arguments (-1, 2, 3) to switch the visible content.
More information here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm

Comment: This got the results I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, this is my first answer on stackoverflow, going to print this ;)

Comment: Congrats on your first answer! :D